# Difficulty Reloading TableView In Swift

Tags: ios, uitableview, swift

I've skimmed through a variety of tutorials and posts on this subject, but I can't seem to get a resolution working for my project.  Essentially, I am trying to implement a "pull to refresh" in my TableView on iOS, which would then reload some data via a web server and then reload my table with the latest dataset.

From testing, it seems as though my "pull to refresh" is working, wherein I am successfully able to pull the latest data from my web services request.  What seems to be failing, however, is that the table's cells are not actually updating with the latest data.  Here's what I have in my **TableViewController**;

```
import UIKit

class MinionsTableViewController: UITableViewController {
let minions: [Minion]
required init(coder aDecoder: NSCoder!) {
    minions = Minion.fetchMinionData()
    super.init(coder: aDecoder)
}

override func viewDidLoad() {

    super.viewDidLoad()
    let defaults = NSUserDefaults(suiteName: "group.com.example.myapp.data")
    NSKeyedArchiver.setClassName("Minion", forClass: Minion.self)
    defaults?.setObject(NSKeyedArchiver.archivedDataWithRootObject(minions), forKey: "minions")

    self.refreshControl?.addTarget(self, action: "handleRefresh:", forControlEvents: UIControlEvents.ValueChanged)
}

func handleRefresh(refreshControl: UIRefreshControl) {
    let minions: [Minion]
    minions = Minion.fetchMinionData()
    for minion in minions {
        println(minion.now!)
    }
    self.tableView.reloadData()
    refreshControl.endRefreshing()
}

override func tableView(tableView: UITableView, numberOfRowsInSection section: Int) -> Int {
    return minions.count
}

override func tableView(tableView: UITableView, cellForRowAtIndexPath indexPath: NSIndexPath) -> UITableViewCell {
    let cell = tableView.dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier("minionCell", forIndexPath: indexPath) as! UITableViewCell

    let minion = minions[indexPath.row]

    if let name = minion.name {
        cell.imageView?.image = UIImage(named: minion.name!)
        cell.textLabel?.text = minion.name ?? "Minion"
        cell.detailTextLabel?.text = "Data: \(minion.now!)"
    } else {
        cell.imageView?.image = UIImage(named: "Dave")
        cell.textLabel?.text = "No data available."
        cell.detailTextLabel?.text = "Sorry, nothing to present here!"
    }

    return cell
}

override func prepareForSegue(segue: UIStoryboardSegue, sender: AnyObject?) {
    if segue.identifier == "ShowDetail" {
        let indexPath = self.tableView.indexPathForSelectedRow()
        //println(indexPath)
        let minionDetail = minions[indexPath!.row]
        let controller = (segue.destinationViewController as! UINavigationController).topViewController as! DetailedViewController
        controller.detailItem = minionDetail
    }
}

override func viewWillAppear(animated: Bool) {
    super.viewWillAppear(animated)
    if let selectedIndexPath = self.tableView.indexPathForSelectedRow() {
        self.tableView.deselectRowAtIndexPath(selectedIndexPath, animated: true)

    }
}
}
```

My "minion.now!" variable is some JSON data with the current timestamp, and from my println output, I can see that it is in fact updating as I pull to refresh.  However, my table's cells do not seem to update at all with each pull.

Any thoughts would be most appreciated.  Thank you!

Comment: let is for constants, use var in the cell variable.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In this below method, you are creating a local variable, which does not have any relation with your class property.

```
func handleRefresh(refreshControl: UIRefreshControl) {
    let minions: [Minion]//Delete this line
    minions = Minion.fetchMinionData() //self.minions = Minion.fetchMinionData()
    for minion in minions {
        println(minion.now!)
    }
    self.tableView.reloadData()
    refreshControl.endRefreshing()
}
```

So convert the line to

```
self.minions = Minion.fetchMinionData()
```

and the property you declared at the class level make it like

```
var minions: [Minion]
```

Full code..

```
import UIKit

class MinionsTableViewController: UITableViewController {
var minions: [Minion]
required init(coder aDecoder: NSCoder!) {
    minions = Minion.fetchMinionData()
    super.init(coder: aDecoder)
}

override func viewDidLoad() {

    super.viewDidLoad()
    let defaults = NSUserDefaults(suiteName: "group.com.example.myapp.data")
    NSKeyedArchiver.setClassName("Minion", forClass: Minion.self)
    defaults?.setObject(NSKeyedArchiver.archivedDataWithRootObject(minions), forKey: "minions")

    self.refreshControl?.addTarget(self, action: "handleRefresh:", forControlEvents: UIControlEvents.ValueChanged)
}

func handleRefresh(refreshControl: UIRefreshControl) {
    self.minions = Minion.fetchMinionData()
    for minion in minions {
        println(minion.now!)
    }
    self.tableView.reloadData()
    refreshControl.endRefreshing()
}

override func tableView(tableView: UITableView, numberOfRowsInSection section: Int) -> Int {
    return minions.count
}

override func tableView(tableView: UITableView, cellForRowAtIndexPath indexPath: NSIndexPath) -> UITableViewCell {
    let cell = tableView.dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier("minionCell", forIndexPath: indexPath) as! UITableViewCell

    let minion = minions[indexPath.row]

    if let name = minion.name {
        cell.imageView?.image = UIImage(named: minion.name!)
        cell.textLabel?.text = minion.name ?? "Minion"
        cell.detailTextLabel?.text = "Data: \(minion.now!)"
    } else {
        cell.imageView?.image = UIImage(named: "Dave")
        cell.textLabel?.text = "No data available."
        cell.detailTextLabel?.text = "Sorry, nothing to present here!"
    }

    return cell
}

override func prepareForSegue(segue: UIStoryboardSegue, sender: AnyObject?) {
    if segue.identifier == "ShowDetail" {
        let indexPath = self.tableView.indexPathForSelectedRow()
        //println(indexPath)
        let minionDetail = minions[indexPath!.row]
        let controller = (segue.destinationViewController as! UINavigationController).topViewController as! DetailedViewController
        controller.detailItem = minionDetail
    }
}

override func viewWillAppear(animated: Bool) {
    super.viewWillAppear(animated)
    if let selectedIndexPath = self.tableView.indexPathForSelectedRow() {
        self.tableView.deselectRowAtIndexPath(selectedIndexPath, animated: true)

    }
}
}
```

Comment: This worked perfectly, @Amit89!  Thank you so much for clarifying.  This made much more sense to me and allowed me to continue my learning.  I appreciate it!